# Get last 5 of rows in database and sort by ASC

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, limit

How can I get the last 5 of the rows in the database and sort it ascending? This is my code:

```
$this->query("
    SELECT  `chat`.`message`,
            `users`.`username`,
            `users`.`user_id`
    FROM    `chat`
    JOIN    `users`
    ON      `chat`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
    ORDER BY `chat`.`timestamp`
    DESC
    LIMIT 5
");
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! The tags you've used seem to be a sentence. They should be a description of the languages/technologies you are using. This looks to be PHP and MySQL. Is this correct? Could you edit your question to indicate what you are using.

Comment: Just use a sub-query, with the inner query having `ORDER BY chat.timestamp DESC LIMIT 5`, and the main query should have `ORDER BY chat.timestamp ASC`

Comment: Are you getting errors or the wrong result ?

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from (
    SELECT  `chat`.`message`,
            `users`.`username`,
            `users`.`user_id`,
            `chat`.`timestamp`
    FROM    `chat`
    JOIN    `users`
    ON      `chat`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
    ORDER BY `chat`.`timestamp`
    DESC
    LIMIT 5
) 
order by timestamp asc
```

Comment: @user1925371 - Does your `users` table have a `timestamp` field? If so, edit that last line to `order by chat.timestamp asc`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is codeigniter, so retrieve data in array and loop backward.
else modifying your query to select  ascending

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CodeIgniter Active Record, then change:

```
$this->query
```

to

```
$this->db->query
```